# How to overide a feature method in Folium

Tags: python-3.x, overriding, gis, folium

I am using the [LatLngPopup()](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/folium/features.py#L1359-L1381) *Folium* function to get the map coordinates to pop-up when I click on a map. However, the accuracy is severely limited to only `4 decimals`, which are useless when you are zoomed into a small area.

```py
class LatLngPopup(MacroElement):
    """
    When one clicks on a Map that contains a LatLngPopup,
    a popup is shown that displays the latitude and longitude of the pointer.
    """
    _template = Template(u"""
            {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
                var {{this.get_name()}} = L.popup();
                function latLngPop(e) {
                    {{this.get_name()}}
                        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                        .setContent("Latitude: " + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(4) +
                                    "<br>Longitude: " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(4))
                        .openOn({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                    }
                {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', latLngPop);
            {% endmacro %}
            """)  # noqa

    def __init__(self):
        super(LatLngPopup, self).__init__()
        self._name = 'LatLngPopup'
```

I want to override this class with better precision, and tried to use something like this:

```py
class GetLatLngPopup(LatLngPopup):
    _template = Template(u"""
            {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
                var {{this.get_name()}} = L.popup();
                function latLngPop(e) {
                    {{this.get_name()}}
                        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                        .setContent("Latitude: " + e.latlng.lat.toFixed(7) +
                                    "<br>Longitude: " + e.latlng.lng.toFixed(7))
                        .openOn({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                    }
                {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', latLngPop);
            {% endmacro %}
            """)

    def __init__(self):
        super(GetLatLngPopup, self).__init__()
        self._name = 'GetLatLngPopup'
```

However, this is not working, giving the error:

```
class GetLatLngPopup(LatLngPopup):
NameError: name 'LatLngPopup' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, when you start asking the right questions, you sometimes find the answer sooner, than you expected.

The solution to the above was that I needed to re-import the specific functions I am overriding with:

```py
from folium.features import LatLngPopup
from jinja2 import Template

# Then use my own class without the folium prefix:
#folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
GetLatLngPopup().add_to(m)
```

Then it works!